# Using Realm and Remote Debugging fails on android

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, realm

Importing and using Realm on react native works fine for iOS. Android also works in terms of functionality, however, when using remote debugging on chrome the following error yields.

[image]

I've looked around almost everywhere and nobody seems to have a clear cut answer for this. Anyone here that has managed to get out of this pit? Remote debugging is quite essential as the app is dealing with rather complex objects and using `react-native log-ios` is a little hard on the workflow.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into known issues w/ android remote debugging, but they're being worked on. You can track progress here: https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/491

Comment: argh so even if we manage to fix that error, the debugging will still be unusable in the current state? Thanks for posting about it. It's such a pity, it felt like the ideal storage solution on RN (after facing the limitations of AsyncStorage & react-native-storage) :( I guess I'm gonna have to find sthing else, again! Good luck with reworking the debugging part, it looks like a big chunk of work!

Answer (score 3):

Easy fix is to goto `node_modules/realm/lib/browser/rpc.js` and replace line 216 with `let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8083/' + command;`

Comment: finally this was the one that worked for me. 
for realm 10.0, update `sessionHost` in rpc.js
`let sessionHost = '127.0.0.1:8082';`

Answer (score 1):

I've met this problem when I've used react native with realm database. I think you need manually port reverse and forward to avoid conflict port.When you enable debug mode, please open command line and follow below command:

```
   `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`
   `adb forward tcp:8082 tcp:8082`
```

Then, you can reload and go into debug mode.

Cheer!

Comment: Unfortunately i ve tried that to no end :/. Any other potential helpful hints? Thank you for your time.

Comment: @GeorgeAvgoustis plz try again!

Comment: I tried. However it seem to mess up with the rest of the configuration. Im getting an adb server no response error. I imagine that by changing the ports something gets messed up.

Im on Ubuntu using a google provided android simulator ( as opposed to using genymotion for example )

Answer (score 1):

if answer from @johnny didn't work, when you type the commands

`adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`
   `adb forward tcp:8082 tcp:8082`

and you get the following message

```
adb server is out of date.  killing...
* daemon started successfully *
```

that means that the adb command you are using in command line, and the adb tool used by the emulator are different.

you can confirm that by checking the location of adb (here I have two different tools in /usr/bin and /home, which are not symlinks as verified after)

```
42:~/pathToMyApp$ whereis adb
adb: /usr/bin/adb /home/42/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb /usr/share/man/man1/adb.1.gz
```

I tried with the full path on both tools, and I discovered the emulator was using the adb tool in /home/...
So to make it work I now type

```
/home/42/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081;
/home/42/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb forward tcp:8082 tcp:8082
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue in my pixel_3XL simulator android API level : 29

reset the path for platform-tools
changed my PATH to platform-tools

```
$ export PATH=${PATH}:/root/Android/Sdk/platform-tools

$ adb kill-server
$ adb root                      #will give root access for adb

$ adb forward tcp:8082 tcp:8082 
$ adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

$ react-native run-android      #restart the server with a debugger enabled
```

voila, it worked in my machine... good luck.

additionaly try changing the ip to 127.0.0.1 and port manually in app's Developer menu -> Dev settings -> Debug server host & port

Answer (score -1):

Doing this worked for me

on terminal:

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
adb forward tcp:8082 tcp:8082
adb forward tcp:8083 tcp:8083
```